# "I have a cold" hay variaciones regionales?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales

*Ahora mismo llevo un poco más de un año aprendiendo Español. Durante este tiempo he alcanzado un nivel donde puedo hablar sobre lo que quiero sin pensarlo mucho. Llegué a este nivel porque al principio conocí a alguien de Bogotá, Colombia a travers de una aplicación y hablé mucho con ella.*

*Porque nos llevamos mucho tiempo hablando, sin duda iba a haber un momento cuando uno de nosotros estaría enfermo. Y después de un tiempo esto (obviamente) pasó. Ella fue la primera estar enferma.*

*Porque así lo aprendí, dije algo como, "Estas enferma? Suena así." (No sé de verdad lo que dije porque pasó hace mucho tiempo.) Y ella me dijo, "No, tengo gripa." Y me acuerdo que me sentí confundido porque ella sí estaba enferma, fue obvio.*

*Como hace un principiante, busque al internet "Tengo gripa" para ver lo que significó. Y el internet me dijo que significa "I have the flu." Así que yo le pregunté a mi amigo, "Oh no, tienes el gripe como la influenza. Qué malo."*

*Ella me dijo "No, no, no gripa."*

*Con la respuesta que me dio, decidí que gripa significa "cold" y además con todo este confusion decidí seguir a la próxima tema porque no pensé que iba a poder entender más con más tiempo.*

*Y pareció como si tenía razón porque la próxima vez que lo dije cuando tenía gripa (jaja) lo dije así y ella no dijo nada.*

*Ya he usado mucho este término con ella y funciona cada vez.*

*El otro vi un video (en Español) llamada "El Coronavirus vs el Gripe" y pensé otra vez del término que uso hoy en día "tengo gripa." Y pensé buscarlo otra vez. Y otra vez no encontré nada.*

Así que mi pregunta es cómo se dice "I have a cold"? Y es el término "Tengo gripa" solo una cosa que dicen en Colombia (o solo Bogotá) o es una cosa que dicen en el mundo hispanohablante entero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesante. Es gripe, que equivale a `influenza`. En Colombia (creo que en ningún otro pais) lo llaman `gripa`. Y en ambos casos es un sustantivo femenino. `cold` sería un resfrío. `estoy resfriado` (con un adjetivo) o `tengo un resfriado` (con un sustantivo).

Comment: así que en Columbia no se puede usar "Tengo gripa" para significar "I have a cold" y solo "tengo un resfriado" es correcto? Alguien sabe?

Comment: O sea tengo gripa solo significa "I have the flu"?

Comment: Si señor.... o mejor dicho: sipirilí.

Answer (score 0):

"I have a cold" puedes traducirlo como "tengo un resfriado" que es generalmente más suave que una gripe. 
Gripa y gripe son lo mismo, pero solo se usa gripa en Colombia y México.

Espero que tu amiga mejore :)

Comment: No son lo mismo. Igual que en Inglés no es lo mismo cold y flu. Un resfrío es una respuesta a una exposición a condiciones de frio/humedad, etc.... la gripe es producida por un virus, el de la influenza.

Comment: @eftshift0 bueno el resfriado también es producido por un virus https://medlineplus.gov/spanish/ency/article/000678.htm que no es el mismo que el de la gripe (o gripa en algunos sitios). Algunas personas dicen "he pillado un enfriamiento está mañana" y a la tarde ya se encuentran bien. Por lo que en español también tenemos termino para la gripe (influenza o flu en ingles) o resfriado (common cold).